# Vowpal Wabbit: command not found

Tags: python, installation, command-line, vowpalwabbit

I want to run Vowpal Wabbit on the generated file.
The file itself:

```
all_documents = newsgroups['data']
all_targets = [1 if newsgroups['target_names'][target] == 'rec.autos' 
                 else -1 for target in newsgroups['target']]

train_documents, test_documents, train_labels, test_labels = \
                                 train_test_split(all_documents, all_targets, random_state=7)

with open('20news_train.vw', 'w') as vw_train_data:
    for text, target in zip(train_documents, train_labels):
        vw_train_data.write(to_vw_format(text, target))

with open('20news_test.vw', 'w') as vw_test_data:
    for text in test_documents:
        vw_test_data.write(to_vw_format(text))
```

Since I solve the classification problem, I set the loss function to the hinge value (linear SVM). I save the constructed model to the corresponding file 20news_model.vw:

```
!vw -d 20news_train.vw --loss_function hinge -f 20news_model.vw
```

**But this is where the error comes out.**

```
/bin/sh: vw: command not found
```

I've installed VW via "`conda install -c conda-forge vowpalwabbit`".

Comment: Even I have installed using "conda install -c conda-forge vowpalwabbit". I could even import the package in python. But I want to use vw from command line. I am getting vw: command not found error.

Answer (score 0):

You're installing the Python bindings for VW and then trying to use the command line interface.

Either you'll need to install the command line binary. You can find instructions for building from source [here](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Dependencies). Or you can use brew on MacOS.

Or, you can use the Python bindings to drive the learner. You can find a tutorial for that [here](https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials/python_first_steps.html)

Comment: Yeah, but command line ```conda install -c conda-forge vowpalwabbit``` works in conda interface + I analyzed the guide for VW, everything works on conda (in guide).

Why do I need a brew? I've already installed the VW package.

Probably, gone try another things. Write you later.

Comment: First link doesn't help: still ```/bin/sh: vw: command not found```. And I've installed a gigabyte of some garbage and another python 3 x)